# How to insert image into the table in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I am newer in CKEditor 5. And I want to know how to insert image into the table in CKEditor 5. But image can insert into the table in CKEditor4. Why? Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images were not allowed in tables prior to CKEditor 5 v12.0.0. Since this version images and media can be inserted into the tables:

[image: Screenshot of images in tables in CKEditor 5]